# mod_rewrite - how to change my links in htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

due to a software update in my forum's software, there have been a change in the links' structure, too.

The old links were like:
https://mywebsite.com/index.php/Thread/4835-some-topic-name/

The new links are now like:
https://mywebsite.com/index.php?thread/4835-some-topic-name/

As google has indexed my website with all those old links, I need a proper redirect to the new structure.

I tried already something like:

RewriteRule ^index.php/Thread/(.*) /index.php?thread/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

But that did not work at all :( I will be redirected to the main website.

If doing that:
RewriteRule ^index.php/Thread/(.*) index.php?thread/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

I will be redirected to:

https://mywebsite.com/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite/httpdocs/index.php?thread/4835-some-topic-name/

Need help, please!

Thank you!

Comment: You need perhaps another flag, like QSA - query string append. - The problem with the path perhaps can be controlled via RewriteBase directive (IIRC) but from what you write in your question, this looks like some more grave configuration issues on your webserver.

Comment: I also tried this:
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

but then, it will only work, if the "Thread" will be written without capital letter from the very beginning:

https://mywebsite.com/index.php/thread/4835-some-topic-name/

redirects properly to the new destination, however with "Thread" in it, it wont.